# How to upgrade targetSdkVersion 33

Tags: android, flutter, targetsdkversion

I am currently using Flutter V2.5.0. I updated to targetSdkVersion 33, however, I can't open it and am stuck in the APK file installation process.

How can I update to targetSDK 33 and keep Flutter version 2.5.0?

Comment: how did you update the targetSdkVersion?

Comment: Same here. Did you get any solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

open `android folder` > `app folder` > `build.gradle`

**Before upgrade---**

`targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion`

[image]

**After upgrade---**

`targetSdkVersion 33`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

open build.gradle file

replace `compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion` with `Math.max(flutter.compileSdkVersion, 33)`

replace `targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion` with `targetSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.targetSdkVersion, 33)`

and

replace `minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion` with `minSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.minSdkVersion, 23)` if required.